# Is it a good practice to use long int to avoid overflow?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have declared following variables :

```
some_dataType a,b,c;  //a,b,c are positive
int res;
res=a+b-c;
```

And I have been provided with the information that the variable `res` cannot cross integer limit. Just to avoid overflow from the expression `a+b` in `a+b-c` I have following options-

1. declare a,b,c as long int
2. `(a-c)`+b
3. `(long int)`(a+b-c)  //or some other type casting

My question is which of the above is good practice. Also, just to escape from all this, I prefer doing option 1. But it may increase the memory size of the program (not for this program though, but for large applications).
Assumption : long int is greater than int Thanks @Retired Ninja

Comment: One variable is not going to increase the memory size of your program in any meaningful way, and since your example is incomplete it looks like it would be a variable on the stack anyway.  You're also making an assumption that long is larger than int and it may not be.

Comment: Option 3 is pointless. I'd go for option 2, not because `long` will increase your memory usage (it will not in any meaningful way), but because `long` doesn't necessarily do what you want (it can have the same size as `int`).

Comment: Option 2 could still fail. Take `a = INT_MAX, b = 2, c = 1`.

Comment: @chris "the variable res cannot cross integer limit", which I take as a guarantee that the mathematical result doesn't overflow `int`.

Comment: @T.C., Oh, I misunderstood that part to mean that the calculation shouldn't overflow. Thanks.

Comment: Well if you're not sure a+b-c won't cross the integer value, you HAVE to use a bigger data type. If you do know it can't, however, i guess option 2 would work just fine?

Comment: I'm presumably risking the gods of undefined behavior, but on any sane hardware, how is this an issue?  Given your "guarantee"... if a+b overflows, you'll end then canceling out that by "underflowing" when you subtract c.

Comment: @Foon: Because the compiler may take liberties in optimization that give the correct results for all defined behaviors, but do not behave the way you describe in the case of undefined behavior. Remember, this is a C/C++ program, not just a fancy shorthand for assembly code.

Comment: Do we know if these are positive numbers to start with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no simple, general, portable way to avoid integer overflow.

Using a wider integer type is not a general solution, because there's no guarantee that there is a wider integer type. It's very common for the types `int` and `long` to be the same size on some systems. 32-bit systems typically make both `int` and `long` 32 bits; even some 64-bit systems do the same thing. And some 64-bit systems make both `int` and `long` 64 bits.

You wrote:

> And I have been provided with the information that the variable `res` cannot cross integer limit.

It's best to be careful with terminology. Although the type name `int` is obviously an abbreviation of the word "integer", the words are not synonymous. In C and C++, `int` is just one of several *integer* types; others include `unsigned char` and `long long`.

Presumably what you mean is that the value of `res` must not be outside the range of type `int`, which is `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`.

If you use `long long` for the result, it's likely that you can avoid overflow; you can then compare the result to the values `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, and take whatever corrective action is appropriate if it's out of range. But it's still possible for both `int` and `long long` to be 64 bits. What you do with that depends on how portable your code needs to be.

You cannot safely check whether a signed integer addition or subtraction overflowed after the fact. An overflow in signed arithmetic causes undefined behavior. Typically the result wraps around, but in principle your program could crash before you have a chance to examine the result.

Some compilers might provide functions that perform safe signed arithmetic and tell you whether there was an overflow. Consult your compiler's documentation.

There are ways to test the operands before performing the operation. They're complicated, and I'm too lazy to work out the details, but briefly:

- If the operands of `+` are of opposite signs, or if one operand is `0`, the addition is safe.
- If both operands are positive, the addition is safe if `x` does not exceed `INT_MAX - y`.
- If both operands are negative, the addition is safe if `y` is no less than `INT_MIN - y`.

I do not guarantee that the above is completely correct *I just wrote it off the top of my head), but in most cases it's probably more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Trust, but verify:

```
assert(a > 0);
assert(b > 0);
assert(c > 0);
assert((long)a - (long)c + (long)b <= INT_MAX);

int res = a - c + b;
```

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but you compute the same value multiple times, and don't detect an overflow. Also the issue needs to be detected and handled in the release code, not in asserts.

Comment: @KennyOstrom You are fully right, of course. My code is just a demo whose sole purpose is to emphasize that what's claimed ("something always in such range") it one thing and what's really there is often another thing.